# Is there a way to compute the number of different sets of n single digit integers add up to a given sum?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

I want to find a way to compute, either by a formula or a code, the number of different combinations of n digits that add up to a given sum S
for example, the amount of sets of 3 digits (from the digits 1 to 9) that add up to 7 (so n = 3, S = 7)
you get:
(1,3,4), (1,2,5), (2,5,1)
how can i generalize this for any sum, and any n?
I dont know much about coding or algorithms

I tried brute forcing this and lost my mind

Comment: Sure. What language are you coding this in? When talking sets, (1,2,5) and (2,5,1) is the same.

Comment: Those three groups of three digits each... they sum up to 8, not 7.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Yunnosch my bad, yes they add up to 8

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes those would be the same, combinations matter, permutations don't. I don't know much coding but something like a PHP code I can run on a browser

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the brute force way is to simply iterating through all possible combinations using recursive functions. Eventually, you get the list of combinations with duplicated set of numbers in different order. You can make the number combination unique by converting each combination in the list into sorted tuple and then efficiently removing the duplications

Here's the sample code in Python

```
def sumCombinations(n, s, combination, target):
    if n == 0:
        if s == target:
            return [list(combination)]
        else:
            return []

    ret = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        combination.append(i)
        ret += sumCombinations(n - 1, s + i, combination, target) 
        combination.pop()
    
    ret = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in ret]
    ret = set(ret) # remove duplicates
    ret = [list(x) for x in ret]
    return ret
        
lst = sumCombinations(3, 0, [], 7)
print(lst)
# output: [[1, 1, 5], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

Edit: If you want the digit to be unique, you can add an additional index to keep track of the minimum allowed index in the recursive function

```
def sumCombinations(n, s, index, combination, target):
    if n == 0:
        if s == target:
            return [list(combination)]
        else:
            return []

    ret = []
    for i in range(index, 10):
        combination.append(i)
        ret += sumCombinations(n - 1, s + i, i + 1, combination, target) 
        combination.pop()
    
    return ret
        
lst = sumCombinations(3, 0, 1, [], 7)
print(lst)
# output: [[1, 2, 4]]
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep duplicated set of numbers in different order, you can keep track of a boolean array to see if the number is already used or not instead of index

```
def sumCombinations(n, s, used, combination, target):
    if n == 0:
        if s == target:
            return [list(combination)]
        else:
            return []

    ret = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if used[i]:
            continue
        combination.append(i)
        used[i] = True
        ret += sumCombinations(n - 1, s + i, used, combination, target) 
        used[i] = False
        combination.pop()
    
    return ret
        
used = [False] * 10
lst = sumCombinations(3, 0, used, [], 8)
print(lst)
# Output: [[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3], [1, 5, 2], [2, 1, 5], [2, 5, 1], [3, 1, 4], [3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 3, 1], [5, 1, 2], [5, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: thats good but the digits have to be unique, so (3, 3, 1) is invalid

Comment: @Adithya I see, if that's the case then, we just need to keep track of the allowed digit in the function. I've updated my answer to take that into account

Comment: It seems to me you can optimize this slightly by going from 9 to 1 and then bailing when the sum exceeds the target. E.g. for target=8 and n=3, at (9, _, _) you're already over, so there's no need to recurse.

Comment: Oh I see, I think it should also work for 1 to 9 in the second case by checking `index + s` to see if it's larger than `target` or in the third case by checking if `target - s < i`, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree...

Comment: @taxevader thanks for all the help but i was able to get a gpt to generate a code for me. thanks again for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth

This problem is so small that it isn't worth coming up with an efficient algorithm. My solution is O(k*2^k), where k is the number of digits. That would be terribly inefficient if we needed to worry about k growing large, but when we're limited to 9 digits it takes almost no time at all.

It's easy to compute all possible solutions for digits 1-9 appearing uniquely, as in the table below. The left side shows the number we're summing to, the top is the number of distinct digits, and the body of the table shows the count.

```
    1  2  3   4   5  6  7  8  9
   --------------------------
 1: 1, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 2: 1, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 3: 1, 1, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 4: 1, 1, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 5: 1, 2, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 6: 1, 2, 1,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 7: 1, 3, 1,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 8: 1, 3, 2,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 9: 1, 4, 3,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
10: 0, 4, 4,  1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
11: 0, 4, 5,  1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
12: 0, 3, 7,  2,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
13: 0, 3, 7,  3,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
14: 0, 2, 8,  5,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
15: 0, 2, 8,  6,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
16: 0, 1, 8,  8,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
17: 0, 1, 7,  9,  2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
18: 0, 0, 7, 11,  3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
19: 0, 0, 5, 11,  5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
20: 0, 0, 4, 12,  6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
21: 0, 0, 3, 11,  8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
22: 0, 0, 2, 11,  9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
23: 0, 0, 1,  9, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
24: 0, 0, 1,  8, 11, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
25: 0, 0, 0,  6, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
26: 0, 0, 0,  5, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
27: 0, 0, 0,  3, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0, 
28: 0, 0, 0,  2,  9, 7, 1, 0, 0, 
29: 0, 0, 0,  1,  8, 8, 1, 0, 0, 
30: 0, 0, 0,  1,  6, 8, 2, 0, 0, 
31: 0, 0, 0,  0,  5, 8, 2, 0, 0, 
32: 0, 0, 0,  0,  3, 7, 3, 0, 0, 
33: 0, 0, 0,  0,  2, 7, 3, 0, 0, 
34: 0, 0, 0,  0,  1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 
35: 0, 0, 0,  0,  1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 
36: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 
37: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 
38: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 
39: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
40: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
41: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
42: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
43: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
44: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
45: 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
```

Here's the code I used to generate the table. It's Ruby, but you can treat it as pseudocode.

```
def f()
  num_to_sum_to_count = Hash.new {|h, num| h[num] = Hash.new {|h2, sum| h2[sum] = 0}}
  1.upto(2**9-1) do |i|
    j = i
    sum = 0
    num_digits = 0
    1.upto(9) do |digit|
      if j%2 == 1
        sum += digit
        num_digits += 1
      end
      j /= 2
      break if j == 0
    end
    num_to_sum_to_count[num_digits][sum] += 1
  end
  1.upto(45) do |sum|
    str = "#{sum}: "
    1.upto(9) do |num|
      str += num_to_sum_to_count[num][sum].to_s + ", "
    end
    puts str
  end
end
```

The idea of the code is that the sum of unique digits from 1-9 is always between 1 and 45. We calculate all of these by going through the binary representation of all numbers between 1 & 2^9-1, and treat set bits as integers being included.

E.g., this says there are 4 ways to get 10 with 3 digits. These are 1+2+7, 1+3+6, 1+4+5, 2+3+5.

Answer (score 0):

Just to tell you what problem is called - this is partition of a number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory). Or if order matter, then it is [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)). There is partition function, but no formula is known, it has an exponential grows and computed by brute force basically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)